# Using several git repositories together for a project

Tags: git, github

Suppose I have two git repositories

https://github.com/nobody/foo
https://github.com/nobody/bar

and I have a repository

https://github.com/nobody/thing

I want to have the code in the thing repository use the code in the foo and bar directories. However, I don't want to store foo or bar inside thing. So I don't want submodules or subtrees!  I want the person who downloads thing to also download foo and bar (either by notification or by an automated approach).

If the thing repository had C++ for example which was compiled with gcc, then I would include the flag

```
-I  ../../foo/include
```

when compiling.

The goal is to maximize code reuse and minimize copies of a repository. For example, this way a branch of one repository with a branch of another repository.

Comment: Create packages for `foo` and `bar` according to the dependency manager specific to your programming language and declare them as dependencies of `thing`. The dependency manager will do the rest.

Comment: The *git way* to do this is using submodules or subtrees. If you don't want to use either you're forced to roll your own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best answer to my question so far is to use submodules.